# How to omit fields when serializing Mongoose models in MEAN

Tags: serialization, mongoose, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm working on a MEAN.IO app and I have a Mongoose model that holds a lot of information, more than what the client really needs to know. It's also a fairly large collection, so I was wondering whether it is possible to omit certain fields from serialization when returning the collection from the server to the front end (e.g. via a get request to the API).

Would this be done as part of the Mongoose schema or is it controlled at the MEAN framework level?